# NullPointerException while setting the rating to the rating bar

Tags: android, xml

when i am trying to set the rating(which is retrieved from the remote db) of the rating bar
in the program with the following code i am getting errors as shown below...

```
  09-18 19:57:16.858: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_CONCURRENT freed 43K, 7% free 2775K/2960K, paused 16ms+21ms, total 134ms
  09-18 19:57:17.057: I/Choreographer(1411): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
  09-18 19:57:17.077: D/gralloc_goldfish(1411): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
  09-18 19:57:21.146: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_CONCURRENT freed 20K, 5% free 3211K/3376K, paused 73ms+6ms, total 260ms
  09-18 19:57:21.737: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 361K, 15% free 3032K/3540K, paused 167ms, total 196ms
  09-18 19:57:21.776: I/dalvikvm-heap(1411): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.940MB for 883132-byte allocation
  09-18 19:57:21.976: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 12% free 3894K/4404K, paused 204ms, total 206ms
  09-18 19:57:22.146: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 3893K/4404K, paused 8ms+29ms, total 170ms
  09-18 19:57:22.146: D/dalvikvm(1411): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 94ms
  09-18 19:57:22.156: I/dalvikvm-heap(1411): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.313MB for 392920-byte allocation
  09-18 19:57:22.316: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 4277K/4788K, paused 154ms, total 154ms
  09-18 19:57:25.196: E/demo(1411): {"success":1,"product":[{"site_name":"Lynda","rating":"3.00"}]}
  09-18 19:57:25.297: D/Rating(1411): {"product":[{"site_name":"Lynda","rating":"3.00"}],"success":1}
  09-18 19:57:25.306: D/AndroidRuntime(1411): Shutting down VM
  09-18 19:57:25.306: W/dalvikvm(1411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): java.lang.NullPointerException
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at com.khizer.myproject.online_tut$MyAdapter.getView(online_tut.java:106)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  09-18 19:57:25.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  09-18 19:57:28.536: I/Process(1411): Sending signal. PID: 1411 SIG: 9
```

I am using a list view to display the names of sites that provide online tutorials along with the rating..
the log mentions the error is at line 106,
line 106 is the line after this line

```
String f=new GetRating().execute("Lynda").get();
```

i.e (line below is the 106th line)

```
rbs.setRating(Float.parseFloat(f));
```

here is the complete code...

```
package com.khizer.myproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class online_tut extends ListActivity {


//   ProgressDialog pDialog;
final JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
final String url_get_rating = "http://192.168.1.4/webguide/getrating.php";
final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
final String TAG_RATE = "rating";
String TAG_SITE="site_name";
String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.online_tut);

setListAdapter(new MyAdapter
(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.ot_custlist_textview1,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.online_tutorials_menu)));
}
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    public MyAdapter(Context context,int resource,
            int textViewResourceId,String[] strings){

        super(context,resource,textViewResourceId,strings);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater infalter= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=infalter.inflate(R.layout.online_tut_menu, parent, false);
        final String[] items= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.online_tutorials_menu);

        RatingBar rbs=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_Small);
        ImageView iv= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ot_info_head);
        ImageView iv1=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image_info);
        TextView tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating_text);
        tv.setText(items[position]);


        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in=new Intent(online_tut.this,Info.class);
                if(items[position].equals("Lynda"))
                {
                    in.putExtra("name","Lynda");
                }
                else if(items[position].equals("My Bring Back"))
                {
                    in.putExtra("name","My Bring Back");
                }else if(items[position].equals("New Boston"))
                {
                    in.putExtra("name","New Boston");
                }else if(items[position].equals("NPTEL"))
                {
                    in.putExtra("name","NPTEL");
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(in));

            }
        });

        if(items[position].equals("Lynda"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.lynda);
            try {

                String f=new GetRating().execute("Lynda").get();
                rbs.setRating(Float.parseFloat(f));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("khizer","IEX");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.d("khzer","khzier");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        else if(items[position].equals("My Bring Back"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);

                try {
                    String f=new GetRating().execute("My Bring Back").get();
                    tv1.setText(f);
                    rbs.setRating(Float.parseFloat(f));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
        else if(items[position].equals("New Boston"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
            try {

                String f=new GetRating().execute("New Boston").get();
                tv1.setText(f);
                rbs.setRating(Float.parseFloat(f));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("khizer","IEX");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.d("khzer","khzier");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(items[position].equals("NPTEL"))
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
            try {
                String f=new GetRating().execute("NPTEL").get();
                tv1.setText(f);
                rbs.setRating(Float.parseFloat(f));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("khizer","IEX");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.d("khzer","khzier");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return row;
    }
}
class GetRating extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    /* @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Rating.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Populating list");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }*/

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        int success;
        String f=null;

           try {         
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("site_name",arg[0]));
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                   url_get_rating, "GET", params);
                   // TAG_SITE=arg[0];
                    Log.d("Rating", json.toString());
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                                       .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); 
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                     f=product.getString(TAG_RATE);

                           }
                    else{
                               Log.d("Rating","Site Not Found");
                           }
                       }catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
        return f;

    }

    //protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
      // cancel(true);
     //}

}


}
```

Here are  the xml files:
1)for the list view...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ot_custlist_textview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/ot_head"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ot_custlist_textview1"
    android:clipChildren="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2)xml for list items..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/lynda" />

<include
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.75"
    layout="@layout/star" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_info"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ot_info_image"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info" />

</LinearLayout>
```

other xml used is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ot_info_head"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="23sp" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar_Small"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ot_info_head"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:minHeight="14dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingbar_Small"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ratingbar_Small"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: to confirm is line 106 of your online_tut class (all classes should start with a capital letter and use CamelCase BTW, which means you should change the class name to OnlineTut) this line: `View row=infalter.inflate(R.layout.online_tut_menu, parent, false);`

Comment: @Prmths, oaky...but line 106 is not that,it is after this line    `String f=new GetRating().execute("Lynda").get();`    i.e  
                `rbs.setRating(Float.parseFloat(f));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tv1 and rbs is mising the row in `row.findViewById()` and i think thats why your getting a nullpointer while trying to set the raiting on rbs. you should also get a nullpointer for tv1 :)

Or your not even inflating the View containing those 2 Views at that point.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to read through all this, and answering correctly